# How to mock object's indexer with private setter in NSubstitute?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an interface that is defined like the following

```
 public interface IFoo
    {
        object this[string key] { get; }
    }
```

How can I mock this indexer using NSubstitute?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call the indexer then use `Returns`:

```
var sub = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
sub["hello"].Returns("world");
```